# Parsing multidimensional array php optimal solution

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, multidimensional-array

Got my code for parsing array and I was wandering if there is a faster solution for it.
Right now I am parsing it using foreach loops

Code:

```
        foreach ($pageViews as $platform => $value){
        foreach ($value as $objectType => $value){
            foreach ($value as $objectId => $value){
                foreach ($value as $key => $value){
                    foreach ($value as $keyId => $value){
                        foreach ($value as $ts => $value){
                            $data .="( '".$objectType ."', '".$objectId ."', '".$key ."', '".$keyId ."', '0', '".$ts ."', '".$value ."' ), ";

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Data to parse:

```
(
[android] => Array
    (
        [event] => Array
            (
                [234] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [2016-06-06T23:00:00Z] => 34
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [events] => Array
            (
                [234] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [2016-06-06T19:00:00Z] => 24
                                        [2016-06-06T18:00:00Z] => 10
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[ios] => Array
    (
        [event] => Array
            (
                [234] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [2016-06-06T23:00:00Z] => 18
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [events] => Array
            (
                [234] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [2016-06-06T19:00:00Z] => 10
                                        [2016-06-06T18:00:00Z] => 8
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Result example : ('ios', 'events', '234','2016-06-06T19:00:00Z', '24')

Is there a better and faster solution do it?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: And what should the result look like???

Comment: OMG!!! Why so many loops?

Comment: Result example : ('ios', 'events', '234','2016-06-06T23:00:00Z', '34')

Comment: In the inner `foreach` loop, you concatenate a string onto `$data`, then immediately overwrite `$data` by assigning an array to it. It's difficult to tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just edited the question, ignore that part :)

Comment: So the result should be a string containing a lot of those `('ios', 'events', '234','2016-06-06T23:00:00Z', '34')` type items?

Comment: yes, its a page view data that i have to store into the DB so each row inserted has to have that information.